# App to streamline complex printing configuration

Tags: windows, windows-7, pdf, printing

I have a web application which generates PDFs to print that are out of the ordinary in terms of their size. Being in Europe, we normally print sheets of paper that are A4, but these PDFs are A5. Thus, to print them, every time I have to click on the Advanced Settings in the print dialog, change the size of the paper and then change to use the Bypass instead of the normal tray.

Is there a way to streamline this process? For example, is there a program that could take into account these settings and then I could drag and drop the file on it? I'm on Windows 7.